# /boot partition filled - updates will not complete

Tags: boot

my last update failed because /boot did not have room for the new kernel (or so I guess).  Can I safely use rm to blow away the old vmlinuz.*-generic?

Thanks

Comment: can you say what kind of distro you are using, anyway, use the package manager, i think you are using apt

Answer (score 3):

No, you should use your operating specific way of removing old versions of the Linux kernel. (yum for RHEL based like CentOS or Fedora, apt-get for Debian based like Ubuntu and so on)

Comment: On Ubuntu (and possibly Debian) the command to use would usually be `apt-get autoremove`. I don't remember the `yum` equivalent.

Comment: autoremove will remove dependencies installed for purged packages. It will not remove old kernels.

Comment: Not sure which system you are referring to. On Ubuntu 14.04 `apt-get autoremove` does remove older kernels, and it is not the first Ubuntu release working like that.

Comment: Ok, after a little bit of research, you are right, with one glitch: by default the Kernel image is present in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove in the neverautoremove area so what you are saying will not work exactly as expected all the time. Also, autoremove would probably remove ALL older versions of kernels. You may want to keep at least the previous one, just in case.

Comment: I only see firmwares in that section, not the kernels themselves. Keeping one known to be working kernel installed is always a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

It's always good to leave at least 1-2 old kernels available in case the new one shows some regressions.

On Fedora/RHEL/CentOS, install the `yum-utils` package and run the following command `package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=1` to clean old kernels before upgrading.

Never `rm` system components previously managed by RPM/DKPG, unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=1 was exactly what I was looking for - cheers